"Has" vs "Have" - which sentence is grammatically correct?
I posted a question on Politics.SE with the title:

Has Trump's political views changed on Israel's war in Gaza?

Another user felt it wasn't grammatically correct:

Nitpick: shouldn't the title be “Have Trump's political views…”, what with ‘views’ being plural?

I can never remember all the rules of English grammar. Which sentence is correct?
(An older question - Has or Have? Which is grammatically correct and why? - wasn't much help).

It's helpful here to undo the subject-verb inversion that makes this sentence a question and turn it into a statement:

Trump's political views has changed on Israel's war in Gaza. [incorrect]

or

Trump's political views have changed on Israel's war in Gaza. [correct]

The subject is views and the verb is has/have changed. Has always goes with a singular subject, and have with a plural one. Since views is plural, the correct choice is have.
With subject-verb inversion you might get confused because the auxiliary have ends up closer to the noun Trump (which is singular), but the subject of the sentence is still the plural views and therefore the verb is still have.
You would use has if Trump were the subject (giving both question and statement forms):

Trump has changed his political views on Israel's war in Gaza.
Has Trump changed his political views on Israel's war in Gaza?

Note the difference in structure from the sentence you provided.

Thanks! This is a great explanation in a very a simple and intuitive manner. And, as you rightly guessed, I was indeed focusing on Trump as the subject.
